# How to correctly use the visitor pattern with different Shapes for an Editor

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

I am creating a editor for different Shape Objects. I stumbled upon the visitor pattern which actually fits my needs I think.
I have a `Element` class which holds a field named `attrs`

```
public class Element {
    ...   
    private Shape attrs;
    ...
}
```

My `Shape` class looks like this with the visitor design pattern.

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void accept(ShapeVisitor v);

    public interface ShapeVisitor{
        public void visit(CircleObject circle);
        public void visit(RectangleObject rectangle);
    }
}
```

And the actual instance of a `Shape` is defined in a `RectangleObject` class which extends Shape and holds the `Rectangle` field. The reasoning for this structure is that I am serializing and deserializing with Jackson for a specifig JSON layout.

```
public class RectangleObject extends Shape {

    private Rectangle rect;

    public class Rectangle {
        private String fill;

        public String getFill() {
            return fill;
        }
        public void setFill(String fill) {
            this.fill = fill;
        }

    @Override
    public void accept(JointShapeVisitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
      }
    }
```

And finally my Editor implements the vistor methods.

```
public class Editor implements ShapeVisitor{
@Override
    public void visit(CircleObject circle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void visit(RectangleObject rectangle) {

    }


    public void setComponent(JsonArray arguments){
      Element element = getFromJson(arguments);
      visit(element.getAttrs()); // *** this does obv. not work ***
    }
}
```

The `element.getAttrs()` returns `JointShape`, but I need here a `CircleObject` or a `RectangleObject`.

---

How can I pass the correct instance of the ShapeObject to the visit method? Am I doing something completely wrong?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is

```
public void setComponent(JsonArray arguments){
  Element element = getFromJson(arguments);
  element.getAttrs().accept(this);
}
```

And you'll get a callback into one of the visit methods. What you don't get is a return value.

This can be a bit tricky to handle because the callback code is suddenly in no relation to the method that called the `accept` method. But you often want to pass arguments back and forth between the visiting method and the method that that called `accept`. To do that, you can add a little to the pattern:

```
@Override
public Object accept(JointShapeVisitor v, Object context) {
    return v.visit(this, context);
  }
}

public interface ShapeVisitor{
    public Object visit(CircleObject circle, Object context);
    ..
}
```

Maybe with a bit of generics to make it typesafe. But even without you can suddenly do

```
public class Editor implements ShapeVisitor{
    @Override
    public Foo visit(CircleObject circle, Object context) {
          return new Foo(circle, (String) context));
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(RectangleObject rectangle) {

    }


    public void setComponent(JsonArray arguments){
      Element element = getFromJson(arguments);
      Foo foo = (Foo)element.getAttrs().visit(this, "Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be best approach to pass arguments? Essentially I would create new Instances every time I update a ShapeObject.

Comment: @MuratK. Depends on what need. If the `visit` methods need input beyond what they have (i.e. they have the visited object and all the private variables of the `Editor`, they don't have the local state of the method that called `accept`). The pattern works fine without arguments in a lot of cases. But I have found myself in need of "communicating" with the visitor method so I made a version with arguments out of it.

Comment: I have opened a new [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000755/which-design-pattern-could-be-used-for-a-shape-editor-visitor-pattern-in-use-fo) regarding this question. You may want to look it at.

Answer (score 3):

Well ... one little mistake. Because you correctly declared an `accept` method in your `Shape` class, you simply must call it:

```
element.getAttrs().accept(this);
```

So simply call the accepting method of a shape by providing the editor itself as a visitor. The callback in the shape implementation will call the correct visitor mehod.