# Which design pattern could be used for a shape editor? Visitor pattern in use for now

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

In hindsight of my question from [earlier about the usage of the visitor pattern for a shape editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999177/how-to-correctly-use-the-visitor-pattern-with-different-shapes-for-an-editor/33999296?noredirect=1#comment55755518_33999296) I came to the conclusion that I have to break the design rules of it.
Mainly because I need to update my `Shape` fields, so essentially I need to pass arguments back to the visitor.

Right now I am population the UI fields with the variables of the ShapeObject.

```
public class Editor implements ShapeVisitor{

    private Shape shape;

    @Override
    public Foo visit(CircleObject circle) {
          // populate fields
          shape = circle;
          ((CircleObject) shape).getText().setCaption("test");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(RectangleObject rectangle) {
          // populate fields
           shape = new RectangleObject();
    }


    public void setComponent(JsonArray arguments){
      Element element = getFromJson(arguments);
      element.getAttrs().accept(this);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my code I have a Save Button which should update the ShapeObject.

```
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    element.setAttrs(shape);    
        }
```

Basically what I am doing is that I create a new Instance of a `ShapeObject` and update the fields there. Then I pass it to the `element` back via `element.setAttrs(shape)`.

---

Essentially I would not need the visitor pattern at all, because I could achieve the same with the `instanceof` operator in the `setComponent` method. I am trying my best to avoid this operator, because in the near future I will have way more `ShapeObjects` then these two. 
I am not really sure if this is the approach I should take or maybe there is a even better one for a custom shape editor.

Best regards.

---

The Shape class looks like this with the visitor pattern

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void accept(ShapeVisitor v);

    public interface ShapeVisitor{
        public void visit(CircleObject circle);
        public void visit(RectangleObject rectangle);
    }
}
```

The approach with `instanceof` would be this

```
public void setComponent(JsonArray arguments){
      Element element = getFromJson(arguments);
      if(element.getAttrs() instanceof RectangleObject)
        shape = new RectangleObject;
    }
```

Comment: can you make an example showing the use of instanceof? I don't see why you need the visitor pattern or instanceof. Is `this.shape = element.getAttrs()` not the same?

Comment: @zapl By doing that I will get the Superclass `Shape`, so I have to cast it into a `CircleObject` or a `RectangleObject ` or other future Shapeobjects. Added my Shape class for better clarification

Comment: Not sure I understand but the actual type of an object does not change because you don't see it. Whatever it's `instanceof` type is remains unchanged even if you assign it to a variable of type `Object`. You merely can't access the "interface" of the concrete type because your reference limits the view. Casting changes the view (or crashes if the view is unavailable)

Comment: @zapl I see what you mean. I updated my visit method for the `CircleObject`. The cast does not work out either. I would have to cast it everywhere...Not so sure how to solve this.

Comment: Don't cast circle.setText... It's the same object and the whole point of the visitor pattern to use the reference you get via the method parameter

Comment: @zapl I want to use that shape reference outside of the method visit for the editor so I can modify it fields. That is the idea at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96657/discussion-between-zapl-and-murat-k).